# STM32G4 cosf(x) allmost 6 times faster than arm_cos_f32(x)?

Tags: arm, stm32

Until now I was convinced, that the ARM-Math functions are always faster than the "normal" ones.

To check that, I did a quick benchmark on a STM32G473

The Code:

```
#define REPS 170000000
uint32_t rep = REPS;
uint32_t start = HAL_GetTick();
float value;

while(rep--) {
    value = cosf(0.0F);
}
uint32_t end = HAL_GetTick();
duration[0] = end - start;

rep = REPS;
start = HAL_GetTick();

while(rep--) {
    value = arm_cos_f32(0.0F);
}
end = HAL_GetTick();
duration[1] = end - start;

rep = REPS;
start = HAL_GetTick();

while(rep--) {
    value = arm_cos_q15(0);
}
GetTime();
end = HAL_GetTick();
duration[2] = end - start;
UNUSED(value);
```

The results were:

- Loop 1 (cosf): 11004 Milliseconds
- Loop 2 (arm_cos_f32): allmost a Minute (58 Seconds)
- Loop 3 (arm_cos_q15): ~46 Seconds

Is there something wrong in my test setup (compiled in DEBUG mode), or is it really true, that cosf(x) from math.h is almost 6(5) times faster than the arm math function?

Comment: Do you get a different result if you take the cosine of something other than zero? I can imagine scenarios where special values like zero are handled in a different way.

Comment: yes, you are right. I created an array with different angles, and then the arm_cos_f32(x) is factor ~2.3 times faster then cosf(x). The results are so far: for x != Zero: cosf(x) needs ~20 Clock Cycles, arm_cos_f32(x) ~9 and arm_sin_cos_f32(x) ~15 Clock Cycles. But these results may even be to slow, because i changed the index (pointer) to the angle value array to calculate the cosinus on in every loop cycle.

Comment: yeah, a number of problems with this benchmark.   will see if I can create one...

Comment: you using hard float or soft?

Comment: and both were built the same way?

Comment: are you using glibc, newlib, etc?

Comment: struggling to find it in glibc but in newlib there is a special path and that is probably why 0.0F returned quicker.  it does have a number of if-then-elses where the cmsis solution quickly gets you to a table.   newlib also has some double math in the single float cosf, which means even with an fpu you are looking at some soft float math.

Comment: there is literally only one special case return on cosf() with newlib and that returns a 1.0F

Comment: i am using hard float on an STM32G473. And yes, it was an issue with my benchmark. If I had used any other number than 0.0F, the initial outcome would have been completely different. I am now using arm_sin_cos_f32(x) and use an if/else for the case, that x is Zero. This benchmark was good for finding out that it makes sense to handle x==0.0F separately, anything else is crap.

Comment: you cannot test for x==0.0F exactly.  I get 33 clocks for arm_cos_f32(x)  on an stm32f411r3  should be the same cortex-m4 maybe not the same flash implementation but should be the same st flash cache front end so similar performance.   same timing with a change to the code alignment.  if I change the alignment of the loop that calls it I can get 32 clocks.  I think the m4 fetches a word at a time so only need to test the two alignments.  On my part that 32/33 clocks gets  you up to about 30mhz I think.  with one wait state 0x3C  (it is 0x32/0x33 above) clocks.

Comment: moving the sin table to ram does not make a difference in performance.

Comment: well running all of this from ram wont have the flash wait state issues for higher frequencies, but wont have the prefetch/cache thing in front of the flash...YMMV.

Comment: point is you can compare clocks to mine and see how your benchmark is if a lot different then we can try to figure out why.

Comment: thanks for your offer and your efforts, but they are unnecessary. My (pragmatic) view is: I need the cos/sin in my software. No way around that. I want to use the fastest implementation. I found out my first benchmark was "problematic", because I was calculating for 0°/0 rad. With a better benchmark I got enough info to make the pragmatic decision: i use arm_sin_cos_f32(x). As i get the angle from an encoder, which is an integer value when it "enters" the system, in my case I can test for exactly 0 because all angles (in rad) are derived from that orignal integer.

Comment: the 15 Clock cycles on an G473 for arm_sin_cos_f32(x) while picking a new x from an pre-generated array for each calculation is good enough for my purpose.

Comment: *There are also built-in versions of the ISO C99 functions ... cosf*  The original test case was faulty.  You want no more help.  Can we close?

Comment: yes, you can close if you want. the original test case was unqualified.

Comment: "Is there something wrong in my test setup (compiled in DEBUG mode)".  Yes there is but if you are happy you can just delete this or self answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

yes, the test was faulty.

If the angles used to calc sin/cos differ from zero, the ARM-Math Function is aprox. 2 times faster than cosf(x)